# Exponential decay of a random matrix falling into a ball

Tags: pr.probability, real-analysis, probability-distributions, random-matrices, matrix-analysis

Let $A=U\Sigma V^T\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be a random matrix defined in the following way: $U,V$ are uniformly distributed on the orthogonal group $O(n)$, $\Sigma$ is a diagonal matrix such that the diagonal elements follows a multivariate Laplace distribution $(\Sigma_{11},...,\Sigma_{nn})\propto\exp(-\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n\Sigma_{ii}^2})$ and $U,V,\Sigma$ are all independent. I conjecture that
$$\mathbb{P}(\|A-B\|_F\leq a)\geq C_1\exp(-C_2\|B\|_F)\mathbb{P}(\|A\|_F\leq a)$$
for any non-random matrix $B$, for some constant $C_1, C_2>0$ not depending on $B, n, a$. Here $\|\|_F$ means the Frobenius norm. This conjecture says that the probability the random matrix $A$ falles into a ball with some given radius decays at most exponentially fast as the center of the ball moves away from the origin.

This conjecture is indeed true if the distribution of $A$ follows $A\propto\exp(-\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^nA_{ij}^2})$, however this is not the case.

If the original conjecture is too hard, is the following relaxation true?
$$\mathbb{P}(\|A-B\|_F\leq a)\geq C_1\exp(-C_2\|B\|_F)\mathbb{P}(\|A\|_F\leq C_3a)$$
where $C_1, C_2, C_3>0$ are some constants.

Comment: am I allowed to take $C_1=0$?

Comment: Have added the non negative constraint.